# Make sure only one instance of event-handler is triggered at a time in socket.io

Tags: python, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I am trying to build a node app which calls python script (takes a lot of time to run).User essentially chooses parameters and then clicks run which triggers event in socket.on('python-event') and this runs python script.I am using sockets.io to send real-time data to the user about the status of the python program using stdout stream I get from python.But the problem I am facing is that if the user clicks run button twice, the event-handdler is triggered twice and runs 2 instances of python script which corrupts stdout.How can I ensure only one event-trigger happens at a time and if new event trigger happens it should kill previous instance and also stdout stream and then run new instance of python script using updated parameters.I tried using socket.once() but it only allows the event to trigger once per connection.

Answer (score 0):

I will use a job queue to do such kind of job, store each job's info in a queue, so you can  cancel it and get its status. You can use a node module like kue.

Comment: Can you provide explaination as to how it can be integrated with socket.io